# Remove Sockjs debug info from console? (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, sockjs

For some reason sockjs prints a bunch of request info into my console.
I have not told it to do so anywhere in my code.

For example;

```
GET /echo/info 1ms 200
GET echo/332/ed2323/websocket 1ms 
etc
```

Is it possible to turn this of somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adjust the logger verbosity level of Sock.js, like in Socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241972/adjust-the-logger-verbosity-level-of-sock-js-like-in-socket-io)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure those logs are from express or sockjs. For sockjs you can override that by providing a custom handler for `log` when creating sockjs server

```
function logger(severity, message){
  if (severity=="error") console.log(message);
}

var sockjs_server = sockjs.createServer(log: logger);
//give empty function if you don't want any logs !!!
```

See the [project page](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) for more info on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the dev-mode access log from express. Comment out the line that says `app.use(express.logger())`